# SAS: Extract every last unique combination ordered by date

Tags: sorting, sas, duplicates

I'm having difficulty in extracting unique tasks performed by workers in events arranged by time. The unique combination is defined by ID and Mode. Following dataset mimics the scenario :

```
  ID        Time       Mode     Event
 23456     20120101    A        Open
 23456     20120101    B        Closed
 87690     20120311    G        Closed
 98000     20120201    B        Open
 98000     20120301    A        Open
 98000     20120101    A        Open
 87889     20121009    C        Closed
 87889     20120101    C        Open
 87900     20120411    A        Closed
 87900     20120102    A        Closed
```

Hope for the following result:

```
  ID        Time       Mode     Event
 23456     20120101    A        Open
 23456     20120101    B        Closed
 87690     20120311    G        Closed
 98000     20120201    B        Open
 98000     20120301    A        Open
 87889     20121009    C        Closed
 87900     20120411    A        Closed
```

I will first sort by time in descending order:

```
  proc sort data=df; by ID descending time; run;
```

Then I can use sort again to get unique combo by ID and Mode:

```
  proc sort data=df dupout=nodup nodupkey;
     by ID Mode; run;
```

In the last step, how do I ensure that the none-duped record is also the latest event?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by using first. and last concept

```
data have;
 input ID        Time:yymmdd8.      Mode $    Event $;
 format time yymmdd10.;
  datalines;
 23456     20120101    A        Open
 23456     20120101    B        Closed
 87690     20120311    G        Closed
 98000     20120201    B        Open
98000     20120301    A        Open
98000     20120101    A        Open
87889     20121009    C        Closed
87889     20120101    C        Open
 87900     20120411    A        Closed
 87900     20120102    A        Closed
  ;

 proc sort data = have out=have1;
 by id mode time;
 run;

 data want;
 set have1;
 by id mode time;
if last.mode and last.time then output;
 run;
```

or i you can simple proc sql as shown below

```
proc sql;
create table want1 as
select id, time, mode,  event from have
 group by  id, mode
 having time = max(time);
```

for your code to work, in your first sort you need to be your first sort as
 proc sort data=df; by ID mode descending time; run;